# Cannot figure out how to assign a callbacks return value into another property (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this

So im using a libary called vue-calendar and it has an object called calendarOptions that contains methods to dictate how it functions. One is the dateClick method that is returning the date that was clicked on the calendar in string format. I want to save that value in arrivalDate but it wont work. I've looked up Vue.set() but I think it is more to do with what 'this' is pointing to. Ive worked around this before by just reassigning this before the function but i cannot do that here.

```
export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar,
    Banner
  },
  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [dayGridPlugin, interactionPlugin],
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        selectable: true,
        dateClick: function(info) {
          this.arrivalDate = info.dateStr
        }
      },
      arrivalDate: ''
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick) example

```
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
```

You need to use [methods](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods)

```
    // you define a method inside your Vue instance
    export default {
     components: {
      FullCalendar,
      Banner,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        ...
        arrivalDate: '',
        calendar: null,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      dateClick(info) {
        this.arrivalDate = info.dateStr;
      },
    },
    created() {
      const self = this;
      this.calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ interactionPlugin ],
        dateClick: function(info) {
         self.dateClick(info);
         // or self.arrivalDate = info.dateStr;
        }
      });
}
```

Then you pass the method to your component

`<VCalendar @dateClick="dateClick" ...>`

Comment: No dateClick has to be a function within the CalendarOptions object. It hooks into methods built into the libary to expose the info variable. If i place the dateClick function like you, info wont have a value

Comment: Can you post a link to that library?

Comment: sure thing. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue im currently looking through their docs too

Comment: ok i think this is definatly the right track. So this is launching an instance of Calendar and passing properties to it within the created hook. then just attacking an event listener for dateClick on the component. This makes sense to me but im getting an error on calendarEl. Says it is not defined

Comment: You can get the element as a ref: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-refs-to-access-your-application-dom-in-vue-js/